# Difference between `medcouple()` implementation in R and Python

Tags: python, r, statsmodels

I discovered a difference between `medcouple()` implementation in **R** and **Python**. Consider an array comprised from **10** repeated 480 times and trailed with **[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]**. For this array `medcouple()` in **R** and **Python** returns different results.

The following **R** code returns 0:

```
library(mrfDepth)
values = c(rep(10, 480), 
c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21))
medcouple(values, FALSE)
```

However the following **Python** code:

```
from statsmodels.stats.stattools import medcouple
arr=[10.0]*480 + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
medcouple(arr)
returns 1!
```

IMHO **R** is right here, but is there any original developers who can comment on this?

Comment: I've run the python code, and `medcouple(arr)` is returning 0, not 1.

Comment: I tried too, I think the code got corrected since the time this question was posted.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your data, <s>one can expect that medcouple is small, but positive</s>. Medcouple is a measure of skewness. As it is stated by [Hubert and Vandervieren](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mia_Hubert/publication/257293348_An_adjusted_boxplot_for_skewed_distributions/links/00b7d524c4c1fc6450000000.pdf):

> It clearly follows from this definition that the medcouple always lies between −1 and 1. A distribution that is skewed to the right has a positive value for the medcouple, whereas the MC becomes negative at a left skewed distribution. Finally, a symmetric distribution has a zero medcouple.

In your data, you have a lot of 10s, plus 9 values to the left (1 to 9) and 11 values to the right (11 to 21). So, it is <s>little</s> skewed to the right.

<s>In your calculations, they are returning zero due rounding</s> (I've checked your python code and it is returning 0, not 1.) But if you put not so many 10s in the data, you could see a small positive value:

```
> medcouple([10.0]*3 + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])
array(0.05263158)
```

**Update**

Actually, my initial interpretation were wrong... Sorry about that!

I've checked the R code you provided, and it is returning 1, not zero as you saw. I've also plotted (using R) the medcouple for different samples (adding different amounts of 10s to the initial data).

I've used not only `mrfDepth` library, but also `robustbase` that also implements medcouple statistic. They've returned the same values.

Just to help understanding the behavior of this asymmetry measure, I've added some plots using the skewness statistic.

And, at last, to make things more interesting, I've compared all these results with a very similar data sample (only omitting 2 numbers: 20 and 21).

See code below:

```
library(robustbase) # mc (also a medcouple implementation)
library(mrfDepth) # medcouple
library(moments) # skewness

symmetric.sample = function(n) {
    c(c(1:19), rep(10,n))
}
skewed.sample = function(n) {
    c(c(1:21), rep(10,n))
}

xlab = "# 10s added"
n = 1:150

png("skew.png", width=600, height=1000, pointsize=8, res=160)
par(mfrow=c(4,2), pch=20)
hist(sapply(30, symmetric.sample), breaks=0:21, xlab="symmetric sample (with 30 10s added)", main="")
hist(sapply(30, skewed.sample), breaks=0:21, xlab="skewed sample (with 30 10s added)", main="")
plot(n, sapply(sapply(n, symmetric.sample), robustbase::mc), col="red", xlab=xlab, ylab="robustbase's mc on symmetric sample")
plot(n, sapply(sapply(n, skewed.sample), robustbase::mc), col="red", xlab=xlab, ylab="robustbase's mc on skewed sample")
plot(n, sapply(sapply(n, symmetric.sample), medcouple, do.reflect=FALSE), col="red", xlab=xlab, ylab="mrfDepth's mc on symmetric sample")
plot(n, sapply(sapply(n, skewed.sample), medcouple, do.reflect=FALSE), col="red", xlab=xlab, ylab="mrfDepth's mc on skewed sample")
plot(n, sapply(sapply(n, symmetric.sample), skewness), col="red", xlab=xlab, ylab="skewness on symmetric sample")
plot(n, sapply(sapply(n, skewed.sample), skewness), col="red", xlab=xlab, ylab="skewness on skewed sample")
dev.off()
```

[image: skewness plots]

Now, regarding python's stattools results, the results were quite different. Adding 4 or more 10s do the original data (1 to 21), medcouple returns 0.

I've tested [Jordi Gutiérrez Hermoso's python implementation](http://inversethought.com/hg/medcouple/file/9a531463663e/medcouple.py). It was consistent with R medcouples functions.

Comment: I am flattered that you tested my implementation, but I would like to add something. Although you seem to have specifically gone through the Mercurial history to find the WIP version of the file just before I added the GPL header, note that the file was always covered by the GPL, as it's a translation of the R original. If you did this in objection of the GPL, note that you would have had less rights to the file without the GPL, such as the right to download it and study it as you did.

Comment: But to be clear, since my code was always covered by the GPL as it was derivative work of the R original (I translated the C code by reading it as closely as I could), you did not exercise any rights you didn't have. I am merely pointing out that the GPL granted you rights, and that looking for a version of the file without the GPL header, if this is what truly happened, is a pointless gesture.